# select only rows with row name in a file

Tags: linux, select, row

I have a big but well formatted file 'A'. The first column stores the name of each row. I have another file 'B' stores the names which I am interested in. How can I select the rows having a name in file 'B'? This is simple in idea, but I am unfamiliar with LINUX.

File 'A': the data file. The first column is the name, separated with the 2nd column by \tab. The other columns are separated by comma.

```
col1    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
col2    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
col3    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
col4    0.1111,0.2222,0.33333,0.4444
```

File 'B': the rows with interest, stored in one column.

```
col1
col3
col4
```

Comment: a small example would be helpful: what names from B do you want to select? what do you need A for? what do you need to do with them? print to stdout?

Comment: @Pavel yes I added an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep in A for every line in B:

```
for f in `cat B`; do grep -w "^$f" A >> output.txt; done
```

or simpler

```
grep -f B A > output.txt
```

please note that the lines in B need to be valid regular experssions

Comment: I tried both, but it seems only to return the row matching only the last name in B. I am not sure why is like that

Comment: then your example was too simplistic - there's something about your data that is different from the example

Comment: yes this works. I got incorrect result because of the difference of new line in Windows and Linux